# Javascript onClick not working on Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a dynamically generated form with some radio buttons.For each radio button there will be a **onClick/onChange** Function.

The problem is that whenever radio button is clicked ,**the onClick of the the first form radio button is called**.

```
<form name="a" id="a">
<input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="func(1);"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="func(2);"/>
</form>
.
.
<form name="f" id="f">
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="func(3);"/>
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="func(4);"/>
</form>

<script>
function func(val){
alert(val);
}
</script>
```

I tried with **onchange** function also its not working.
Always the first form's radio button function is called and `alert(1)` is shown everytime.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is working check here http://jsfiddle.net/g6c2rsnw/

Answer (score 0):

How about like this. I assume that the value you put as parameter on `func()` is the value of that radio button. 
If so, then you can change your HTML markup to this:

```
<form name="a" id="a">
<input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="func(this);" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="func(this);" value="2" />
</form>
.
.
<form name="f" id="f">
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="func(this);" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="func(this);" value="4" />
</form>
```

Instead of passing the value as parameter to the function, use the `value=""` attribute (which I think much better). Then pass `this` as your parameter which will contain the HTML dom where the onClick was triggered.

Then on your javascript:

```
<script>
function func(val){
    alert(val.value);
}
</script>
```

[Check this FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/6zqn5xe0/3/)

Comment: I have tried this its not working.It takes the first forms radio button values.Is there any other way?

Comment: you mean other way to get radio button value on click event?